# Trigger CSS Transition on component prop changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to fade in/out a component whenever its prop changes. Some basic examples I've found achieve this via a boolean condition that toggles the element's styles, but I want to update the toggle state via a prop change.

For example, in my code sandbox, I have a few buttons that when clicked, will update the text on screen. I want to be able to fade in/out this text whenever the user clicks on a different option.

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: "dog",
      isVisible: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true });
  }

  handleOnClick = option => {
    this.setState({ current: option });
  };

  // only used to test css transition
  forceToggleState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isVisible: !prevState.isVisible }));
  };

  render() {
    const options = ["dog", "cat", "rabbit"];
    return (
      <div>
        {options.map((option, index) => (
          <button onClick={() => this.handleOnClick(option)} key={index}>
            {option}
          </button>
        ))}
        <div style={this.state.isVisible ? styles.toggleIn : styles.toggleOut}>
          {this.state.current}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.forceToggleState}>toggle me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  toggleIn: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: "all 0.5s ease",
    border: "1px solid red"
  },
  toggleOut: {
    opacity: 0,
    transition: "all 0.5s ease-in"
  }
};
```

[current sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-7vpzm)

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the body of your question, in addition to the link. It will make sure the question is still relevant to anybody that finds it in the event that link ever becomes dead.

Comment: I would also look at [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) package, it is what I always use. There are also some nice higher level wrappers you can use, but this gets the job done.

Comment: I usually do this kind of thing by adding/removing a specific class and have the transition itself be defined in the css.

Answer (score 5):

Solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-lyf3f

I made a few edits to your sandbox to achieve the desired functionality.

1. Move `options` array into `state`
2. Pass `this.state.current` as a `prop` to an `Option` component
3. Create a `toggleIn` animation using an @keyframes to create the desired animation
4. Set the `key` prop equal to `this.props.current` in the `Option` component to make sure the DOM element remounts any time the `this.props.current` changes. This will ensure our animation runs each time the `this.props.current` changes.